# How do I define a cost function to trade latency and throughput?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, queueing-theory

I have a system that is a pipeline of three functions. Function `P` is a message producer. Function `PA` is a pre aggregate of data. Function `C` is a consumer of data. The pipeline is `P -> PA -> C`. I have some known parameters:

- the capacity of function `C` to process messages given in message/sec is fixed.
- the capacity of the channel `PA -> C` to handle messages given in message/sec (bandwidth) is fixed.
- the throughput of messages coming to the function `C` given in message/sec I can monitor.

the unknown variable is:

- the throughput that the function `P` generates messages.

My goal is to have a maximum throughput of messages going to function `C` without exceeding the capacities that I said before. This is my objective function. Can I say that?

I do that by adjusting the latency on the `PA` function. I cannot always set the latency to 0 because it can exceed the capacity of the channel `PA -> c` or the function `C`. And besides that, the workload of messages on the function `P` varies with respect to time.

I have the insights in steps to adjust the latency:

1. adjust the latency on the `PA` function only with the capacities of the function `C` of the channel `PA->C` is almost ~100%.
2. measure the latency of the message and if the current latency is bigger than a previous measurement (when the capacities were not exceeded) we know that messages are queueing.
3. calculate how many times the latency increased on the function `C` and increase the latency on the function `PA` to the same degree (e.g.: if increased 3 times on the `C` I increase the latency 3 times on the `PA`). Thus, the throughput decreased and it is affordable by the capacity of the channel `PA->C` and to the function `C`.

My question is, how do I define a cost function to such a system? I believe that I described all the dynamics of my system, didn't I? I was studying [Little`s Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) and [Single Server model in queueing theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue). It gave a lot of insights into my step-by-step method. But How should I formulate a cost function for that?

Comment: Can you provide equations of your systems? Also, it is not clear to me what you mean with "deterministic finding an equilibrium using a Lyapunov function".

Comment: Hi @SampleTime, I defined more less what are the parameters in my function that I have to take into account. The equilibrium is a throughput that can use the max capacity that I have on the parameters.

Comment: Since you are asking about crafting a Lyapunov function: such a task always depends on your specific system dynamics, because there is no general method to construct such functions. So, you will have to provide more details, i.e. equations that describe the *dynamics* of your systems. Are your systems linear/nonlinear? Continous/discrete? Why do you mention "deterministic", are there random variables involved? You mentioned you want to use a Lyapunov function when you are "not in A1, A2 or A3", but doesn't that mean your channels are not saturated and so you can just set the latency to zero?

Comment: I end up looking for a course to understand better the terminologies that you are using. What do you suggest? Control theory or Machine Learning or another thing? In the end I need to have a cost function which describes a trade-off for latency on my PA system in order to increase the thoughput on the CS. The CS has a capacity and the workload that the PA system is consuming is variable. This means that if the workload is high I might increase the latency on the PA system to not excced the throughput on the CS. But if the workload is low I do the opposite. What course do you suggest? thanks

Comment: Hi @SampleTime I've changed the question to define a basic cost function to my problem. I was trying to use the Lyapunov function, but maybe it is better to start with a simple function and then improve it. Would you help?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't really help you then, because the question is not related to Lyapunov functions/stability anymore. With *dynamics*, I meant [ODEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) (or their discrete version), which are not specified. About advises what to study, doesn't your third tag, "queuing theory", sound like the right way to go? Unfortunatly, I'm not familiar with that field...

Comment: ok. thanks anyway